# Size of a class with virtual base class

Tags: c++, virtual, multiple-inheritance, virtual-inheritance, abi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [object size with virtual](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2038717/object-size-with-virtual)

```
class X {};  
class Y : public virtual X {};  
class Z : public virtual X {};  
class Class : public Y, public Z {};
```

Why sizeof(Class) outputs 12 on my gcc compiler? Would someone please explain?

Comment: Why are you tagging this `c` ?

Comment: What flags you have used during compilation?

Comment: @Space: No, this is about virtual inheritence, not virtual functions.

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/396327/.

Comment: @Xeo: The question covers both.

Comment: @Space: Derp, should've scrolled some more. :P

Comment: I believe lakshmanan is asking "why not 8?"